# C++: Designing a component-based entity system - advanced problems

Tags: c++, components, entities

In my game engine, that is written in C++, I've moved away from the classical hierarchical entity system and build up a component-based one. It works roughly in this way:

An entity is merely a container for components. Some example components are: Point, Sprite, Physics, Emitter.

Each entity can hold at most one component of each type. Some component depend on another, like Physics and Sprite depend on Point, because they need a position and angle delivered by it.

So everything works fine with the component system, but now I have trouble implementing more specialized entities, like:

- A camera, which needs additional functions to handle movement and zoom
- A player, which needs support to receive input from the user and move

Now, I could easily solve this with inheritance. Just derive the camera from the entity and add the additional zoom  functions and members. But this simply feels wrong.

My question:

- How can I solve the problem of specialized entities with a component system in C++?

Comment: What is the benefit of making cameras and players into entities? Why should they not be their own things, being oddball objects as it is?  I note that what you describe for "player" is really just the Controller end of MVC, and would *not* apply to other players (if present). My main point is: don't create an innovative system just to make it a ball and chain that prevents you from doing the right thing on the unique cases.

Comment: @Mike: I want my entity system to be uniform. The camera is basically nothing more than an entity with a position, and I find that it is logical and the right way to do it like this. The same with the player, no even more, the player has all typical properties of an entity with physics.

Comment: Couldn't you just make new component types for player and camera, like you do for other unique functionality?

Comment: You make the assumption all things can be "entities". What is the advantage to this? In other words "why are you doing this?" If there's no advantage then you're wasting time.

Comment: @Jay: No, but camera and player definitely are entities for me, they are objects that exist in world space.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to separate the in-game representation of the player (which is an entity with physics) from the player as such (the controller of the world). Likewise you could separate the camera-as-entity (which has a position in the world) from the interpretation of that camera (rendering things like zoom, etc).

Answer (score 14):

You seem to be doubting the IS-A relationship here. So why not make it a HAS-A relationship? Instead of being an entity, the camera and the player could be objects that have an entity (or a reference to the entity), but exist outside of your component-system. That way, you can easily keep the uniformity and orthogonality of your component system.

This also fits nicely with the meaning of those two examples (camera/player) as 'glue' objects. The player glues the entity system to the input system and acts as a controller. The camera glues the entity system to the renderer and acts as a kind of observer.

Answer (score 3):

What about just creating components that enable that behavior?  For example, an InputComponent could handle input from the player.  Then your design remains the same, and a player is just an entity which allows input from a keyboard, rather than input from an AI controller.

Answer (score 1):

Components based system usually have a general method allowing to send "messages" to entities, like a function `send(string message_type, void* data)`. The entity then pass it to all its components and only some of them will react to it. For example, your component `Point` could react to `send("move", &direction)`. Or you could introduce a `moveable` component to have more control. Same thing for your camera, add a component `view` and make it handle "zoom" message.

This modular design already allow to define different types of cameras (like a fixed one not having the `moveable` component), reuse some component for other stuff (another type of entity may use a "view") and you can also gain flexibility by having various components handling each message differently.

Of course, some optimization tricks could be needed, especially for frequently used messages.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving each entity some restrictions to what kind of components it may hold (and maybe also what it should hold), and loosening those restrictictions when you derive from that entity. For example by adding a virtual function that verifies whether a certain component can be added to the entity.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to use the visitor pattern. Basically, you'll have your entity being "visited" by a Visitor class. Inside your entity, you'd have :

```
void onVisitTime(Visitor* v)
{
   // for each myComponent...
   v->visit(myComponent);
   // end for each
}
```

And then, you'd have, in the Visitor class :

```
void visit(PointComponent* p);
void visit(CameraComponent* c);
```

Be aware that it's a bit of violation of OOP (data-manipulation being handled outside the object, since the visitor will handle it). And visitors tend to become over-complicated, so it's a not-so-great solution.

Comment: I don't understand how the visitor pattern helps here. It's a dynamic type-dispatch mechanism. The OP's asking how to design his system. I don't see how it relates.

Comment: It eases the specialization of entities : he can just add a ZoomCameraComponent, for instance, and not touch the class hierarchy. But I might have misunderstood the question.